# How do you load a page into a frame in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to load another page into a frame within a grid?

For example, if I have a main page with a content row and column, I want to load another page into that content row and column (ie. frame)?

I know its possible because other apps do it

Thanks a lot

Comment: is this XAML or HTML5/JS

Answer (score 1):

Let the frame navigate to the page, Here is an example for VB.net:

```
frameA.Navigate(GetType(TestPage))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use beter the `<WebView .../>` element to view a webpage.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, not a website but an actual xaml page object or User Control. This is in xaml